# Applying a window function in 2 dimensions

Tags: python, math, signal-processing

I've created a simple sine bell apodization function, which I apply to my data before performing a 2D FFT and making a contour plot of the result, as follows.

```
P = 90
apd_fn = np.sin(((np.pi - (np.pi/180.0) * P) / 1024) * np.arange(0, 1024, 1) + (np.pi/180.0) * P)**2

fid_mat = ws_list * apd_fn
jres_spec = abs(fftshift(fft2(fid_mat)))
max_val = (jres_spec[:,400:]).max()
figure()
CS=contour(jres_spec,arange(0,max_val,max_val/30))
xlabel('frequency (ppm)') 
show()
```

Having been windowed in the x-dimension, this generates a 2D spectroscopy image like so:
[image]

I'd now like to apply the same filter in the y-dimension, but I'm having a bit of a mental block and struggling to work out how to implement this. Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: how do you want the window to look in 2d?  there are many ways to generate a 2d window from 1d function f(t).  you can, for example, rotate the 1d function around a point (0,0) maybe -- g(x,y) = f(sqrt(x*x+y*y)).  you can also just do g(x,y) = f(x)f(y).  there are many other ways....